# Get child of child etc

Tags: xslt

Say I have xml like

```
<1 id="1234">
  <2>
    <3><name>This</name></3>
  </2>
</1>
```

I want to get the name of the most child node, so 3 in this example. But there could be more of less child nodes, so it could go on to have a <4> as a child of the 3, in which case I want the name in that one.
The only constant id is the first node, how could I go about getting that? Not really sure what to search for either, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't XML at all. You may want to take a beginner's course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but you can use an XPath expression such as `.//*[not(*)]` to select descendant elements that do not themselves have any children.